# High performance wrapper for CSPRNG arc4random(3)

Tags: performance, beginner, c, random, cryptography

This function is a wrapper for `arc4random(3)`, a cryptographic pseudo-random number generator on macOS and BSDs, but you can also get it by installing `libbsd-devel` on most Linux distros.

It serves the same purpose as `arc4random_uniform(3)`, the official wrapper for `arc4random(3)`, i.e. to generate a nonnegative random integer less than `range`.

```
static inline unsigned random_uniform(unsigned range) {
    static uint32_t random_32b;
    static uint32_t full_32b;

    if (full_32b < range) {
        random_32b = arc4random();
        full_32b = UINT32_MAX;
    }

    unsigned result = random_32b % range;
    random_32b /= range;
    full_32b /= range;

    return result;
}
```

You can find the implementation of `arc4random_uniform(3)` on macOS at the bottom of [this page](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-1272.200.26/gen/FreeBSD/arc4random.c.auto.html). Basically, it makes use of the rejection method to produce uniform deviates and eliminate the modulo bias. On the other hand, my implementation tries to eliminate the modulo bias by keeping track of the maximum possible range of the remaining random bytes in `full_32b`. What's more, it saves the unused random bytes in a static variable for future use, as a call to `arc4random(3)` can be costly. It appears to be faster according to my benchmark, but I'm not sure if it's correct.

Comment: I recommend viewing [OpenBSD's `arc4random_uniform(3)`](https://github.com/openbsd/src/blob/7e5f239444a6c4227bcf791551e257a58e0e9c4a/lib/libc/crypt/arc4random_uniform.c#L22), which is _far_ cleaner than the macOS one you link. I'd be interested in it's performance according to your benchmarking.

Answer (score 4):

```
result = random % range
```

You can only do this if `range` is constrained to be much smaller than the maximum value of `random`.  Imagine a 2-bit PRNG that returns a value from 0 to 3.   When your function is invoked with range 3, return value 0 will be twice as common as 1 or 2.

```
random_32b /= range;
full_32b /= range;
```

This is going to exhibit obvious bias when the result has a small number of bits.  Imagine a range of 3 and a 4-bit random pool.  On exit, `full_32b` will equal 5 but `random_32b` will only equal 5 one time in 15.

---

There are three good ways to go about this:

1. - choose an acceptable margin of bias (expressed as a fraction);
   - divide `range` by that fraction;
   - select enough bits to make `max(random)` larger than the result of the division;
   - return a simple modulus.

For example, 1% bias is 0.01.  If the range is 10, the random number needs a maximum larger than \$10/0.01 = 1000\$.
That's ten bits.

2. - select enough bits to represent `range`
   - repeat until the result is smaller than `range`.

Example: for a range of 10, consume four bits and discard results larger than 9.

3. - select enough bits to represent `range`, plus a couple more, to represent a multiple of `range`.  Call the multiplier \$i\$.
   - repeat until the result is smaller than \$i * \$`range`
   - divide result by \$i\$

This last approach combines the advanatages of first two: you get bias-free numbers and mostly predictable runtime.

Example: approach #2 with a range of 9 consumes four bits per attempt, and discards almost half of the results.  With 5 bits, instead of 4, you keep results from 0-26 (i.e., `range`\$*3\$) and divide them by 3.  Discard 27 or larger—that's only 5/32 attempts wasted.  With 6 bits and range of 9, values 0-62 are usable (`range`\$*7\$), and only one possible value (63) will be discarded.

In all cases, consume bits by bit-shifting (or dividing by powers of two).  Integer division with arbitrary denominators won't work.